# Sort Date column in Datatable by year and month through LINQ VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting

I am trying to sort the createDate column from my datatable. If I have "09/01/2016", "09/03/2017", "09/04/2016" values, it sorts by month like "09/04/2016", "09/03/2017", "09/01/2016" if sorted in Descending order vs  "09/03/2017", "09/04/2016", "09/01/2016"

This is what I have: sortColumn is "createDate"

```
Dim orderedRows = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                      Let [date] = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Field(Of String)(sortColumn), "dd-mm-yyyy", Nothing)
                      Order By [date]row Descending
                      select row
```

but that doesn't work because if I put the "select" clause, it throws an error. the auto fix in my VB version adds "Select Case" in place of just the "select" and the debugger feels it needs an "end case". Clearly, I'm not looking for any case here!

But without having the select clause, how is my linq query complete?

I also tried converting the column values to date format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" but this is just a conversion from date to datetime which makes it even worse since I don't need the timestamp on these values.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I have looked at a lot of questions posted on stackoverflow but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: You have discovered a **very good reason** to store dates as dates - because then they will act like dates: `dt.DefaultView.Sort = "myDateCol DESC"`

Comment: as @plutonix said its a bad idea to store dates as strings, if you can not fix that column datatype  you can convert it to datetime in your sql query read that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @Plutonix: thanks for your reply. I converted the createDate to Date instead of String and used dt.DefaultView.Sort = "createDate DESC"  like u mentioned but it still doesn't sort based on the year; I am getting the same results like before. Now, I additionally have the time along with the date that I will have to trim. Any thoughts on why it won't work?

Comment: If the column in the datatable is DateTime, it will  correctly sort by the date value. You probably have something else somewhere converting it to string. `Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns(0).DataType)` will tell you.  To save just the date, save the `datetimeVar.Date` - the time element will be zed.  Then you dont 'trim' the time (they are **not** strings), you use a datetime format that just shows the date part.  There is not a lot to go on here. Maybe if you edit your post with what you are now doing it would help.

Comment: BTW, you do know that if you added `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC` to the SQL, none of this is needed, right?  (Assuming the data comes from a DB (unknown))